# Тестирование crud операций REST контроллеров Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, test-driven-development

Здравствуйте!

Интересует вопрос грамотного тестирования crud операций в базу данных посредством REST. Создаваемые объекты могут зависеть от многих других (обязательные внешние ключи). Как быть с этими объектами? Создавать каждый раз перед тестом? Иметь тестовую базу данных? Или что-то ещё?

Буду крайне благодарен за полезные ссылки, рекомендации, хорошие примеры и принципы подобного тестирования.

Используемые технологии: Spring Boot, Spring Boot JPA, Hibernate, PostgreSQL

На данный момент либо ссылаюсь на имеющиеся записи, которые могут измениться/удалиться:

```
private static final Long STUDENT_ID = Long.valueOf(107L);
```

Либо просто тестирую, чтобы не было exception'ов. О проверки правильности результатов поиска, как видите, в тесте речи не идёт:

```
@Test
public void search() {
    UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(ENDPOINT);
    uriBuilder.queryParam("studyPeriod", Long.valueOf(1L));
    uriBuilder.queryParam("curriculumVersion", Long.valueOf(1L));
    uriBuilder.queryParam("studentGroups", Long.valueOf(1L));
    uriBuilder.queryParam("status", "OPINGUKAVA_STAATUS_S");
    uriBuilder.queryParam("repeatingDeclaration", "true");
    uriBuilder.queryParam("insertedFrom", "2017-05-26T00:00:00.000Z");
    ResponseEntity<DeclarationDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriBuilder.toUriString(), DeclarationDto.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
}
```

Тесты на запись либо не пишутся вообще, либо просто кошмарны (более 100 сток на метод).

```
/*
 * TODO: adding/removing subjects
 */
@Test
public void crud() {
    //create declaration
    UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(ENDPOINT + "/create/" + STUDENT_ID);
    String uri = uriBuilder.build().toUriString();
    ResponseEntity<DeclarationDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, null, DeclarationDto.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity.getBody());
    Long id = responseEntity.getBody().getId();
    Assert.assertNotNull(id);

//confirm
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(ENDPOINT + "/confirm/" + id, HttpMethod.PUT, null, DeclarationDto.class);
Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
Assert.assertEquals(DeclarationStatus.OPINGUKAVA_STAATUS_K.name(), responseEntity.getBody().getStatus());

// remove confirmation
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(ENDPOINT + "/removeConfirm/" + id, HttpMethod.PUT, null, DeclarationDto.class);
Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
Assert.assertEquals(DeclarationStatus.OPINGUKAVA_STAATUS_S.name(), responseEntity.getBody().getStatus());

// get
responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(String.format(ENDPOINT + "/%d", id), DeclarationDto.class);
Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());

// get modules 
basicTest(ENDPOINT + "/modules/" + id);

// get curriculum subjects
basicTest(ENDPOINT + "/subjects/" + id);

// get extra curriculum subjects
basicTest(ENDPOINT + "/subjects/extracurriculum/" + id);

// delete
uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(ENDPOINT).pathSegment(id.toString());
uri = uriBuilder.build().toUriString();
restTemplate.delete(uri);
}

private void basicTest(String url) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
}
```

Очень надеюсь, что Ваши советы помогут мне писать тесты более красиво, точно и эффективно!

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Жесть как это дело страшно выглядит. Реально что-ли REST-овые контроллеры в spring-е такие замороченные? И URL-ы туда надо передавать? URL-ы вроде к контроллерам вообще отношения никакого не имеют, это ж маршрутизация. А тест метода контроллера должен выглядеть в пять-десять строчек. У меня по крайней мере именно так они и выглядят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многое зависит от типа тестов, которые вы хотите написать.

**Интеграционные тесты**

Получаются действительно очень сложными. Вы можете:

- Создавать тестовые данные непосредственно в теле теста\тест класса. Тогда тесты получаются на много-много строк, и выглядят страшно
- Использовать базу данных, создавая сущности с помощью дампа\скриптов. В таком случае, тестовые классы\методы выглядят получше, но теряется гибкость и приходится "размазывать" тестовую логику между двумя различными технологиями

То, что интеграционные тесты получаются сложными, это не баг, а фича. Сложная логика и сущности == сложные интеграционные тесты. Выход - только один, писать как можно меньше таких системных тестов. Рекомендую также ознакомиться с замечательным докладом "Integrated tests are scam" https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam

**Системные тесты**

Вы можете создавать сущности посредством вызова самого REST API, создавая условия для каждого теста. Это ОЧЕНЬ муторно и медленно. Получается так же сложно, как и интеграционные, только хуже.

*Есть только один способ писать простые тесты (вне зависимости от тестируемого приложения), и это писать тесты маленького размеры (те самые, что называют unit-тестами).*

Отличные русскоязычные доклады на тему:

- "Пацан накодил - пацан протестил" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8u6_hctdhqI.
- "Автотесты: такие же, но лучше" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYY_52DTJqs

Хоть доклады и не фокусируются на тестировании REST API, идеи они выдвигают абсолютно также применимые и актуальные.

**Я бы не рекомендовал, но если уж очень необходимо писать тесты системного уровня**

Для того, чтобы сделать тесты читабельными, можно и нужно использовать более сложные решения, например "трехуровневый тест фреймворк" (вот подробное объяснение с ссылкой на репозиторий http://aqaguy.blogspot.com/2018/02/test-automation-framework-architecture.html)

**Вместо заключения**

При правильном подходе к построению процесса автоматизации, является ли тестируемое приложение веб сервисом, мобильным приложением или чайником - должно играть наименьшую роль. Важна лишь бизнес логика приложения, все остальное - это лишь "как".
Более подробно - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96fL7pM3gYE

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ! Разные тесты я повидал за те два с половиной года, что прошли с того момента, как я задал тут вопрос. В том числе и те сложные тесты, которые создают больше проблем, чем пользы. Сейчас я действительно предпочитаю юнит-тесты. Вдобавок к простоте, их преимуществом является быстрая скорость исполнения, что довольно важно на больших проектах. 
Надеюсь, когда-нибудь предстоит поработать на проекте, где практикуется Continuous deployment - там качество тестов и самого кода должны быть выше среднего в отрасли.